# Collect and change data into a PLC

Tags: c, plc, modbus-tcp

I am working on a project to collect and change the data into a PLC. I would like to work with any PLC manufacturers so I guess the best way is to create my own modbus communication protocol and not use the OPC protocol (to avoid to be dependant of manufacturers).

What do you think it is the best: OPC protocol or directly in ModBus protocol?

Also, I found modbus libraries libmodbus and nmodbus what do you think about them? Do you think my project is feasible?

Comment: This is not only far too broad but also primarily opinion-based, *and* it is off-topic on account of seeking opinions / recommendations for off-site resources -- a trifecta in just five lines!

Comment: I also agree that this is completely off topic.  Forget about the dream of perfect PLC interoperability.  OPC is as close as you're going to get for a standard.  If you need to solve a real-world problem, first pick a PLC - this will be based on its performance requirements and your budget.  Then pick a protocol to talk to it with - depending on manufacturer sometimes the proprietary tools are faster, easier, better, cheaper (or all of the above) than an OPC solution.  Don't write your own Modbus... you will almost certainly get it wrong.